# Miktex not compiling TexStudio

Tags: xetex, miktex, texstudio

[image: Hello Word example][image: My Thesis Example]I am using a Win 10 Home, and currently almost two days trying to compile a folder with Tex files belonging to my master thesis. I had no problem in my former computer under repair, however I tried install Tec Studio and MikTex and does not matter what a try to do the same compile error
"Sorry, but xelatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\joaoc_000\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\xelatex.log".

I submitted the code regarding the log file below. Please someone help me I have a week deadline and I have no other ideia to how to solve the issue. Best Regards.

```
2022-06-23 01:53:21,070+0100 INFO  xelatex - this process (6724) started by texstudio in directory C:\Users\joaoc_000\Documents\Tese Corrigida(R) with command line: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode Tese.tex
2022-06-23 01:53:21,075+0100 INFO  xelatex - this is MiKTeX-XETEX 4.8.0 (0.999994) (MiKTeX 22.3)
2022-06-23 01:53:21,082+0100 INFO  xelatex - allowing known shell commands
2022-06-23 01:53:21,139+0100 INFO  xelatex - going to create file: xelatex.fmt
2022-06-23 01:53:21,139+0100 INFO  xelatex.core - start process: miktex --enable-installer formats build xelatex --engine xetex
2022-06-23 01:53:23,266+0100 ERROR xelatex - C:\MikTex\miktex\bin\x64\miktex.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2022-06-23 01:53:23,267+0100 ERROR xelatex - output:
2022-06-23 01:53:23,267+0100 ERROR xelatex - Building format 'xelatex' with engine 'xetex'...

Sorry, but: The executed process did not succeed.
.
2022-06-23 01:53:23,267+0100 FATAL xelatex.core - Data: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2022-06-23 01:53:23,267+0100 FATAL xelatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:697
2022-06-23 01:53:23,268+0100 FATAL xelatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2022-06-23 01:53:23,268+0100 FATAL xelatex - Info: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2022-06-23 01:53:23,268+0100 FATAL xelatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2022-06-23 01:53:23,268+0100 FATAL xelatex - Line: 697
2022-06-23 01:53:23,272+0100 INFO  xelatex - this process (6724) finishes with exit code 1
2022-06-23 01:53:38,411+0100 INFO  xelatex - this process (4516) started by texstudio in directory C:\Users\joaoc_000\Documents\Tese Corrigida(R) with command line: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode Tese.tex
2022-06-23 01:53:38,411+0100 INFO  xelatex - this is MiKTeX-XETEX 4.8.0 (0.999994) (MiKTeX 22.3)
2022-06-23 01:53:38,411+0100 INFO  xelatex - allowing known shell commands
2022-06-23 01:53:38,458+0100 INFO  xelatex - going to create file: xelatex.fmt
2022-06-23 01:53:38,458+0100 INFO  xelatex.core - start process: miktex --enable-installer formats build xelatex --engine xetex
2022-06-23 01:53:40,272+0100 ERROR xelatex - C:\MikTex\miktex\bin\x64\miktex.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2022-06-23 01:53:40,272+0100 ERROR xelatex - output:
2022-06-23 01:53:40,272+0100 ERROR xelatex - Building format 'xelatex' with engine 'xetex'...

Sorry, but: The executed process did not succeed.

2022-06-23 01:53:40,272+0100 FATAL xelatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2022-06-23 01:53:40,272+0100 FATAL xelatex.core - Data: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2022-06-23 01:53:40,272+0100 FATAL xelatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:697
2022-06-23 01:53:40,272+0100 FATAL xelatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2022-06-23 01:53:40,272+0100 FATAL xelatex - Info: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2022-06-23 01:53:40,272+0100 FATAL xelatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2022-06-23 01:53:40,272+0100 FATAL xelatex - Line: 697
2022-06-23 01:53:40,272+0100 INFO  xelatex - this process (4516) finishes with exit code 1
```

About the "Tese.log" it is describing all about packages use, tables, figures but references back to the old computer. Evertime I click run it shows the last pdf compile in the old pc. I submitted a snipped (too big).

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 22.1) (preloaded format=xelatex 2022.2.13)  20 JUN 2022 17:43
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./Tese.tex
(Tese.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-05> (estiloUBI.cls
Document Class: estiloUBI 2011/06/18 v1.2 Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\bk11.clo
File: bk11.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@chapter=\count182
\c@section=\count183
\c@subsection=\count184
\c@subsubsection=\count185
\c@paragraph=\count186
\c@subparagraph=\count187
\c@figure=\count188
\c@table=\count189
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)

LaTeX Warning: \include should only be used after \begin{document} on input lin
e 5.

(formatacaoUBI.tex
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/mathspec\mathspec.st
y
Package: mathspec 2016/12/22 v0.2b LaTeX Package (Mathematics font selection fo
r XeLaTeX)

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count190
) (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen139
))
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xpar
se.sty
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-02-05 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xe
tex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: XeTeX
 ()
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count191
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count192
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\g__graphics_track_int=\count194
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count195
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count196
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count197
))
Package: xparse 2022-01-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xete
x.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count271
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count272
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count273
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count274
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen140
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen141
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen142
 (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg)
)) (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count275
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\c@eu@=\count276
\c@eu@i=\count277
\c@mkern=\count278
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen143
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count279
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count280
\leftroot@=\count281
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varTheta on input line 397.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count282
\DOTSCASE@=\count283
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
\big@size=\dimen144
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count284
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count285
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count286
\dspbrk@lvl=\count287
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count288
\column@=\count289
\maxfields@=\count290
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen145
\alignsep@=\dimen146
\tagshift@=\dimen147
\tagwidth@=\dimen148
\totwidth@=\dimen149
\lineht@=\dimen150
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2938.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2939.
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amscd.sty
Package: amscd 2017/04/14 v2.1 AMS Commutative Diagrams
\athelp@=\toks23
\minaw@=\dimen151
\bigaw@=\dimen152
\minCDarrowwidth=\dimen153
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amscls\amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\thm@style=\toks24
\thm@bodyfont=\toks25
\thm@headfont=\toks26
\thm@notefont=\toks27
\thm@headpunct=\toks28
\thm@preskip=\skip52
\thm@postskip=\skip53
\thm@headsep=\skip54
\dth@everypar=\toks29
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\xspace.sty
Package: xspace 2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \digamma on input line 259.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varkappa on input line 260.
) (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 227.

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2021/03/18 v5.0k Graphics/color driver for xetex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count291
\Gm@cntv=\count292
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count293
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen154
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen155
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen156
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen157
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen158
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen159
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen160
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen161
\Gm@dimlist=\toks30

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg)
) (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ae\aecompl.sty
Package: aecompl 1998/07/23 0.9 T1 Complements for AE fonts (D. Roegel)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty
Package: caption 2020/10/26 v3.5g Customizing captions (AR)

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2020/10/21 v2.2e caption3 kernel (AR)
\captionmargin=\dimen162
\captionmargin@=\dimen163
\captionwidth=\dimen164
\caption@tempdima=\dimen165
\caption@indent=\dimen166
\caption@parindent=\dimen167
\caption@hangindent=\dimen168
Package caption Info: Standard document class detected.
)
\c@caption@flags=\count294
\c@continuedfloat=\count295
) (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.st
y
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.
cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen169
\Gin@req@width=\dimen170
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmd
s.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.
sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.
sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefin
ekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.
sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacr
o.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.st
y
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen171
\Hy@linkcounter=\count296
\Hy@pagecounter=\count297
 (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref-lang
patches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: patches for babel la
nguages
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.st
y
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count298
 (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `hyperindex' set `true' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing ON on input line 4210.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\backref.sty
Package: backref 2021/02/04 v1.41 Bibliographical back referencing

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfi
lecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend pac
kage
with kernel methods
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/uniquecounter\unique
counter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcal
c.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
))
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count299
 (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen172
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
)
\Fld@menulength=\count300
\Field@Width=\dimen173
\Fld@charsize=\dimen174
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6081.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6084.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing ON on input line 6089.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6096.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6101.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6146.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6150.

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count301
\c@Item=\count302
\c@Hfootnote=\count303
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.
 (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hxetex.def
File: hxetex.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref driver for XeTeX

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/stringenc\stringenc.
sty
Package: stringenc 2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO
)
)
\pdfm@box=\box53
\c@Hy@AnnotLevel=\count304
\HyField@AnnotCount=\count305
\Fld@listcount=\count306
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count307
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip55
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\rotating.sty
Package: rotating 2016/08/11 v2.16d rotated objects in LaTeX

(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\c@r@tfl@t=\count308
\rotFPtop=\skip56
\rotFPbot=\skip57
\rot@float@box=\box54
\rot@mess@toks=\toks31
)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2021/01/28 v4.0.1 Extensive control of page headers and foote
rs
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip58
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip59
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip60
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip61
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip62
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip63
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip64
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip65
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip66
) (C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/colortbl\colortbl.st
y
Package: colortbl 2020/01/04 v1.0e Color table columns (DPC)
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\array.sty
Package: array 2021/10/04 v2.5f Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen175
\ar@mcellbox=\box55
\extrarowheight=\dimen176
\NC@list=\toks32
\extratabsurround=\skip67
\backup@length=\skip68
\ar@cellbox=\box56
)
\everycr=\toks33
\minrowclearance=\skip69
)
(algorithm.sty
Package: algorithm 

Document Style `algorithm' - floating environment
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/float\float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count309
\float@exts=\toks34
\float@box=\box57
\@float@everytoks=\toks35
\@floatcapt=\box58
)
\@float@every@algorithm=\toks36
\c@algorithm=\count310
)
(algorithmic.sty
Package: algorithmic 

Document Style `algorithmic' - environment
(C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count311
\calc@Bcount=\count312
\calc@Adimen=\dimen177
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen178
\calc@Askip=\skip70
\calc@Bskip=\skip71
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count313
\calc@Cskip=\skip72
)
\c@ALC@line=\count314
\c@ALC@rem=\count315
\ALC@tlm=\skip73
)
```

I guess this is the file Ulrike Fischer refer to along xelatex.log inside makefmt folder. C:/Users/joaoc_000/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/miktex/log/makefmt/xelatex/2022-06-23-02-48-40.log

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (MiKTeX 22.3) (INITEX)  23 JUN 2022 02:48
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**C:/MikTex/tex/latex/latexconfig/xelatex.ini
(C:/MikTex/tex/latex/latexconfig/xelatex.ini
(C:\MikTex\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx (C:\MikTex\tex/latex/base\texsys.cfg)
\openout15 = `texsys.aux'.


./texsys.aux found


\@currdir set to: ./.


Assuming \openin and \input 
have the same search path.


Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.

catcodes, registers,
\@inputcheck=\read0
\@unused=\write0
\maxdimen=\dimen10
\hideskip=\skip10
\p@=\dimen11
\z@=\dimen12
\z@skip=\skip11
\voidb@x=\box10
 parameters,
\normalbaselineskip=\skip12
\normallineskip=\skip13
\normallineskiplimit=\dimen13
\interfootnotelinepenalty=\count23
\strutbox=\box11

LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> pre-release-0 (develop 2022-6-23 branch)
(C:\MikTex\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx
(C:\MikTex\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2022-06-02 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count24
\l_tmpa_int=\count25
\l_tmpb_int=\count26
\g_tmpa_int=\count27
\g_tmpb_int=\count28
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count29
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count30
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count31
\c__ior_term_noprompt_ior=\count32
\c_log_iow=\count33
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count34
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count35
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count36
\l__iow_indent_int=\count37
\c_zero_dim=\dimen14
\c_max_dim=\dimen15
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen16
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen17
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen18
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen19
\c_zero_skip=\skip14
\c_max_skip=\skip15
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip16
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip17
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip18
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip19
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count38
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count39
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen20
\g__intarray_font_int=\count40
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count41
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count42
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count43
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count44
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count45
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count46
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count47
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count48
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count49
\g__fp_array_int=\count50
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count51
\g__cctab_allocate_int=\count52
\l__sort_length_int=\count53
\l__sort_min_int=\count54
\l__sort_top_int=\count55
\l__sort_max_int=\count56
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count57
\l__sort_block_int=\count58
\l__sort_begin_int=\count59
\l__sort_end_int=\count60
\l__sort_A_int=\count61
\l__sort_B_int=\count62
\l__sort_C_int=\count63
\l__str_modulo_int=\count64
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count65
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count66
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count67
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count68
\l__tl_peek_charcode_int=\count69
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count70
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count71
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count72
\l__regex_balance_int=\count73
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count74
\l__regex_mode_int=\count75
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count76
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count77
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count78
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count79
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count80
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count81
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count82
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count83
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count84
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count85
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count86
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count87
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count88
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count89
\g__regex_case_int=\count90
\l__regex_case_max_group_int=\count91
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count92
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count93
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count94
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count95
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count96
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count97
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count98
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count99
\l__regex_last_char_success_int=\count100
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count101
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count102
\l__regex_step_int=\count103
\l__regex_min_thread_int=\count104
\l__regex_max_thread_int=\count105
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count106
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count107
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count108
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count109
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count110
\l__regex_added_begin_int=\count111
\l__regex_added_end_int=\count112
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count113
\c_empty_box=\box12
\l_tmpa_box=\box13
\l_tmpb_box=\box14
\g_tmpa_box=\box15
\g_tmpb_box=\box16
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen21
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen22
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen23
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen24
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen25
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen26
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen27
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen28
\l__box_internal_box=\box17
\l__color_internal_int=\count114
\g__color_model_int=\count115
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box18
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen29
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen30
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen31
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen32
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen33
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen34
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen35
\c_empty_coffin=\box19
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box20
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box21
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box22
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box23
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box24
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box25
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen36
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen37
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen38
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen39
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen40
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen41
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen42
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box26
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box27
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box28
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box29
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen43
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen44
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen45


! LaTeX3 Error: File 'UnicodeData.txt' not found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.31698   }
           
No pages of output.
```

Comment: I added code blocks, which you should always use when posting anything like code, including logs. Does the file `Tese.log` exist in the same folder as your .tex file? What does it say? That output makes me think MikTeX itself is not properly configured and you might want to look into its configuration utilities.

Comment: Please post a minimal Tex example, which does not compile.

Comment: The MikTex installation comes with program TeXworks ... did you use it?

Comment: The error says that the format couldn't be created. You need to find out why. Search for a xelatex.log in the MiKTeX log folder (in a makefmt folder or something like that)  and post it.

Comment: Sorry Guys, I am new into the platform,therefore I might sound unclear.
About the "Tese.log" it is describing all about packages use, tables, figures but references back to the old computer. Evertime I click run it shows the last pdf compile in the old pc.
C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\bk11.clo
file:///C:/Users/joaoc_000/Documents/Tese%20corrected%20some%20new%20files/Tese.log

Comment: This is what show evertime a run.
file:///C:/Users/joaoc_000/Pictures/Screenshots/Captura%20de%20Ecrã%20(1).png
I guess this is the file Ulrike Fischer refer to along xelatex.log inside makefmt folder
file:///C:/Users/joaoc_000/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/miktex/log/miktex-makefmt.log
file:///C:/Users/joaoc_000/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/miktex/log/makefmt/xelatex/2022-06-23-02-48-40.log
This xelatex.log is directed by the error "Sorry, but xelatex.exe did not succeed. 
file:///C:/Users/joaoc_000/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/miktex/log/xelatex.log

Comment: have you tried this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267299/how-to-fix-the-sorry-but-c-miktex-pdftex-exe-did-not-succeed-error or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640845/updated-miktex-now-sorry-but-xelatex-exe-did-not-succeed-the-log-file-hopefu Especially the first link might be interesting, since it provides code that you can use to check if the error persists.

Comment: Sorry I only notice now that I can only share code at the question section. I updated with the code asked.

Comment: You should ping people if you update the question. The format can't find the unicode data. This error happens sometimes on MiKTeX but the reason is unknown.  Try to disable virus checker, or usr texlive instead.

Comment: I had changed to Texlive and it is now working accordingly, thanks.